# Python ggplot Barchart not displaying data as expected

Tags: python, bar-chart, python-ggplot

I'm trying to create a basic barchart using python ggplot implementation. I want the percentages on the y-axis and the type on the x-axis rotated 90deg.  The code I have written is below.

```
from ggplot import *
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Percentage':[91.45, 16.73, 8.61],
                    'Type':['protein_coding', 'antisense_RNA', 'sense_overlapping']})

ggplot(aes(x="Type",y='Percentage'), data=df1) +\
    geom_bar(stat='identity')+\
    xlab('Biotype') +\
    theme(axis_text_x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image: bad barchart]

It has converted my "Types" to numbers and is not plotting the percentages correctly on the y axis. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Don't post images on third-party sites like imgur so we have to click through; also they're ephemeral and disappear. Post your images directly here.

Comment: My post was uploaded there because I don't have 10 reputation, so I cannot embed images. When I tried to, a link was automatically created by stackoverflow.

Comment: Ahh ok. Spam protection. No problem, I reuploaded it directly. Also adding the `from ggplot import *` to your source.

Comment: @smci Our images are hosted by Imgur; it's possible to inline images in these cases simply by surrounding the link with the right image syntax (`[!alt text][1]`, if I recall).